# How to calculate the probability of residents relocating using time series?

Tags: time-series, probability

I have a general question concerning calculating probabilities using time series and would highly appreciate your help.

Suppose I am given a time series (time interval is months) containing information about relocation history, income, family status, age, ... for the years 2005 to 2015. My ultimate goal is it to calculate the probability of relocating. How would you approach this?

One idea I had is to simply use all the data until 2014 (including individual's relocation history) and estimate a model for the probability of relocating in 2015.

Comment: First, refine your target: are you trying to predict whether they will relocate in the next 365 days?

Comment: @ Bey Thank you for you question. That's exactly what I'm planning to. Depending on the data, I might reduce the time frame to less than 365 days. But for now, it's 365 days. How would you approach this?